# Java class reading and writing the <Group> and <Groups> elements from an XML and always show null value

Tags: java, xml

> I'm creating a class to display data from an XML, and I need to show the data of the users along with the groups they belong to.

Here's the output I'm getting:

[image]

The XML I'm reading has the following structure, I'm trying to iterate over the Name elements that are inside Groups > Group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <users report_date="20230620">
 <user>
 <id type="integer">123456</id>
 <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
 <roles type="integer">2</roles>
 <name>RODRIGO BARCAT</name>
 <time-zone>America/Sao_Paulo</time-zone>
 <updated-at type="dateTime">2023-06-15T11:18:54-03:00</updated-at>
 <created-at type="dateTime">2021-10-19T10:37:42-03:00</created-at>
 <external-id nil="true"/>
 <details></details>
 <openid-url nil="true"/>
 <organization-id type="integer">123456789</organization-id>
 <notes></notes>
 <restriction-id type="integer">0</restriction-id>
 <locale-id type="integer">19</locale-id>
 <last-login type="dateTime">2023-06-15T11:18:39-03:00</last-login>
 <current-tags>TEST</current-tags>
 <email>rodrigo@test.com</email>
 <is-verified type="boolean">true</is-verified>
 <custom-role-id type="integer">1260812330129</custom-role-id>
 <groups type="array">
  <group>
  <id type="integer">1900004323624</id>
  <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
  <name>Grupo 1</name>
  <updated-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:20:24-03:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:20:24-03:00</created-at>
  <description></description>
  <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
</group>
<group>
  <id type="integer">5845531840667</id>
  <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
  <name>Grupo 2</name>
  <updated-at type="dateTime">2022-05-20T15:43:09-03:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="dateTime">2022-05-09T12:37:24-03:00</created-at>
  <description></description>
  <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
</group>
<group>
  <id type="integer">1260814988809</id>
  <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
  <name>Grupo 3</name>
  <updated-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:20:41-03:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:20:41-03:00</created-at>
  <description></description>
  <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
</group>
<group>
  <id type="integer">6088614508699</id>
  <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
  <name>Grupo 4</name>
  <updated-at type="dateTime">2022-05-20T15:05:38-03:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="dateTime">2022-05-20T15:05:38-03:00</created-at>
  <description></description>
  <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
</group>
<group>
  <id type="integer">1900004323564</id>
  <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
  <name>Grupo 5</name>
  <updated-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:19:46-03:00</updated-at>
  <created-at type="dateTime">2021-11-03T11:19:46-03:00</created-at>
  <description></description>
  <is-public type="boolean">true</is-public>
</group>
</groups>
<photo-url></photo-url>
<uses-12-hour-clock>false</uses-12-hour-clock>
<phone/>
</user>
</users>
```

And my code is as follows.

```
package com.zendesk2helix.maven.zendesk2helix_jar;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class Usuarios {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlFilePath = "/home/barcat/users.xml";

    try {
        // Criar um XMLInputFactory
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

        // Criar um XMLStreamReader para o arquivo XML
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xmlFilePath));

        // Variáveis para armazenar os elementos desejados
        String id = "";
        String userName = "";
        String groupName = "";

        // Flags para controlar em qual nível estamos
        boolean insideUser = false;
        boolean insideGroup = false;

        // Loop para ler os elementos do XML
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            int eventType = reader.next();

            if (eventType == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                String elementName = reader.getLocalName();

                // Verificar o nome do elemento
                if (elementName.equals("user")) {
                    // Entrar no elemento User
                    insideUser = true;
                } else if (elementName.equals("id") && insideUser) {
                    // Ler o ID do usuário
                    id = reader.getElementText();
                } else if (elementName.equals("name") && insideUser && !insideGroup) {
                    // Ler o nome do usuário
                    userName = reader.getElementText();
                } else if (elementName.equals("group") && insideUser) {
                    // Entrar no elemento Group
                    insideGroup = true;
                }
            } else if (eventType == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
                if (insideGroup) {
                    // Ler o nome do grupo
                    groupName = reader.getText();
                }
            } else if (eventType == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
                String elementName = reader.getLocalName();

                // Verificar o nome do elemento final
                if (elementName.equals("user")) {
                    // Exibir os elementos lidos
                    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
                    System.out.println("User Name: " + userName);
                    System.out.println("Group Name: " + groupName);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

                    // Limpar as variáveis para o próximo usuário
                    id = "";
                    userName = "";
                    groupName = "";

                    // Resetar as flags
                    insideUser = false;
                    insideGroup = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Fechar o XMLStreamReader
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic is incorrect. You are not handling end events for groups at all, and a user has multiple groups.  It would help if you showed the output expected for the given input.  Note also that you may get multiple "characters" events for any given tag, and have to accumulate them; and also deal with non-significant whitespace.  You're probably picking up some whitespace from one of the tags after the last group.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a null value for the groups output. You are getting a whitespace-only value instead.

I modified your code to put a `'` character on either side of the group name in the output, and it gave me this output:

```
ID: 1900004323564
User Name: RODRIGO BARCAT
Group Name: '
'
-----------------------------
```

Your code sets `groupName` to the last element of character data encountered while `insideGroup` is true. This is from an opening `<group>` tag to a closing `</user>` tag. This includes whitespace-only character data which occurs between tags. In this case, we get a single newline, because this is the whitespace between the empty `<phone/>` tag and the closing `</user>` tag.

However you are not interested in any old piece of text within the `group` element. What you are looking for is the text content of the `name` element. To do this you will need to keep track of whether you are inside this element as well as whether you are inside the `user` and `group` elements

You will need to:

- Add a local variable that keeps track of whether you are inside a `name` element within a `group` element:

  ```java
              boolean insideGroupName = false;
  ```

  Add this alongside the other `insideXYZ` boolean variables.
- Add some handling for a `name` element within a `group` element, to set this variable to `true` in this situation:

  ```java
                      } else if (elementName.equals("name") && insideGroup) {
                          insideGroupName = true;
  ```

  Add this to the `if`-`else if` block that handles the start of an element.
- Change the handling of a characters event to only read a value into `groupName` if the new `insideGroupName` variable is true:

  ```java
                      if (insideGroupName) {
                          // Ler o nome do grupo
                          groupName = reader.getText();
                      }
  ```
- Ensure that you set `insideGroupName`, and also `insideGroup`, back to `false` when the end of the relevant elements is reached:

  ```java
                      if (elementName.equals("name")) {
                          insideGroupName = false;
                      } else if (elementName.equals("group")) {
                          insideGroup = false;
                      }
  ```

  Add this to the block that handles the end of an element.

I made these changes to your code, and it then gave me the following output:

```
ID: 1900004323564
User Name: RODRIGO BARCAT
Group Name: Grupo 5
-----------------------------
```

This gives us a group name in the output. However, I note from the top of your question (emphasis mine) that:

> I'm creating a class to display data from an XML, and I need to show the data of the users along with the **groups** they belong to.

So far, all we've got is the last group name. It seems you want all of the group names.

The problem here is that there are multiple groups in your sample XML file, and every time we find a new group name, we overwrite any previous value we might have stored. To fix this, we shall use a `List<String>` to contain multiple group names, instead of using a single `String` value to store a single group name.

Replace the line

```java
            String groupName = "";
```

with

```java
            List<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

You then need to replace the various uses of `groupName` with a suitable use of `groupNames`:

- When reading character data within a group-name element: replace

  ```java
                          groupName = reader.getText();
  ```

  with

  ```java
                          groupNames.add(reader.getText());
  ```
- When displaying the user data read: replace

  ```java
                          System.out.println("Group Name: " + groupName);
  ```

  with

  ```java
                          System.out.println("Group Names: " + groupNames);
  ```
- When resetting the variables after displaying the user details, to prepare for another user in the file: replace

  ```java
                          groupName = "";
  ```

  with

  ```java
                          groupNames.clear();
  ```

I made these changes to your code and it generated the following output:

```
ID: 1900004323564
User Name: RODRIGO BARCAT
Group Names: [Grupo 1, Grupo 2, Grupo 3, Grupo 4, Grupo 5]
-----------------------------
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.